# Installing playframework

Tags: playframework

Having trouble installing play! on windows.

Following the installation guide on: http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/install

After installing and setting up JAVA_HOME and ANT_HOME

in git i typed the commands:

```
    $ git clone git://github.com/playframework/play.git
    $ cd play/framework
    $ ant
```

Build was successful.
But when I type the command:

```
    $ play
```

it doesn't recognize the command.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add the play folder to your path.

By the way, to get 1.2.4 there's really no need to build it yourself: just grab a precompiled package (1.2.4) from http://download.playframework.org/releases/

You still need to add the extracted folder to your path!

Comment: Added the extracted play folder to Paths of my Environment Variables and it is now working. Thank you Stefano.

Comment: @mccallbear you're welcome! if this answer is satisfying you should "accept" it! Even though I know it was an easy one ;-)